# Android fragment illegalstateexception

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

i searched and found custom listview's library and i try to use it (QuickReturnHeaderHelper)
in this library's example used activity and this library can load like this

```
QuickReturnHeaderHelper helper = new QuickReturnHeaderHelper(getActivity(),
            R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.header);
    View view = helper.createView();
    getActivity().setContentView(view);
```

but in my project i use fragment but i do not know how i can use this source code

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            container, false);
    QuickReturnHeaderHelper helper = new QuickReturnHeaderHelper(getActivity(),
            R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.header);
    View view = helper.createView();
    getActivity().setContentView(view);
```

i wrote my code like this but i can not recive result same as a  activity.
how i can change my code if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should override [onCreateView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) of your Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    QuickReturnHeaderHelper helper = new QuickReturnHeaderHelper(getActivity(),
        R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.header);
    return helper.createView();    
}
```

Comment: thanks but i tryed it but i have nullpointexception  View view = helper.createView();
  getActivity().setContentView(view);

  main_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: First, provide stack trace for your exception. Second, again, you shouldn't call `getActivity().setContentView()` from fragment code.

Comment: i debuged and i have nullpoint in this line  main_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: This line is not even present in your question. And I need to know where you call it from, so I need a **full stack trace of the exception**

Comment: There are only system functions in that stack trace. It's apparently not full, there must be something below. Paste it as text to your original question.